# Create a style for a variable in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code to include a point in the map but I'm wondering, I can create a style to include the fillColor and the fillOpacity? instead of using it each time I create a new var? I'll create several points on the map:)! that's why I'm asking it

```
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: {lat: 41.7141904, lng: -87.643531},
    radius: 50
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to create a circle with the fixed parameters you desire, then call it.

```
function createCircle(options) {
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
  circle.setOptions({
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  return circle;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c5od83ym/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function createCircle(options) {
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
  circle.setOptions({
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  return circle;
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.7141904, -87.643531),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var circle1 = createCircle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    map: map,
    center: {
      lat: 41.7141904,
      lng: -87.643531
    },
    radius: 50
  });
  var circle2 = createCircle({
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map,
    center: {
      lat: 41.71,
      lng: -87.643
    },
    radius: 100
  });
  var circle3 = createCircle({
    strokeColor: '#FF00FF',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map,
    center: {
      lat: 41.718,
      lng: -87.6425
    },
    radius: 150
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```